# Logstash cannot extract json key

Tags: json, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I need help regarding logstash filter to extract json key/value to new_field. The following is my logstash conf.

```
input {
    tcp {
        port => 5044
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        add_field => {
            "data" => "%{[message][data]}"
        }
    }
}

output {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I have tried with mutate:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "data" => "%{[message][data]}"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with . instead of []:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "data" => "%{message.data}"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with index number:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "data" => "%{[message][0]}"
        }
    }
}
```

**All with no luck. :(**

The following json is sent to port 5044:

```
{"data": "blablabla"}
```

The problem is the new field not able to extract value from the key of the json.

**"data" => "%{[message][data]}"**

The following is my stdout:

```
{
           "@version" => "1",
               "host" => "localhost",
               "type" => "logstash",
               "data" => "%{[message][data]}",
               "path" => "/path/from/my/app",
         "@timestamp" => 2019-01-11T20:39:10.845Z,
            "message" => "{\"data\": \"blablabla\"}"
}
```

However if I use **"data" => "%{[message]}"** instead:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
        add_field => {
            "data" => "%{[message]}"
        }
    }
}
```

I will get the whole json from stdout.

```
{
           "@version" => "1",
               "host" => "localhost",
               "type" => "logstash",
               "data" => "{\"data\": \"blablabla\"}",
               "path" => "/path/from/my/app",
         "@timestamp" => 2019-01-11T20:39:10.845Z,
            "message" => "{\"data\": \"blablabla\"}"
}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong.

Thank you in advance.

I use docker-elk stack, ELK_VERSION=6.5.4

Answer (score 2):

`add_field` is used to add custom logic when filter succeeds, many filters have this option. If you want to parse json into a field, you should use [`target`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html#plugins-filters-json-target):

```
filter {
  json {
    source => "message"
    target => "data"  // parse into data field
  }
}
```

Comment: I did the same thing and it worked. Thank you for your answer anyway.